# Subspace and Dimension of a Homomorphism/Linear Mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, group-homomorphism, dimension-theory-algebra

I am very confused about the following exercise:

Let $V, W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$. Show that $Hom_F(V, W)$ is a vector subspace of the set of all mappings $Maps(V, W)$ from $V$ to $W$.

It is intuitively clear why the set of all $Hom_F(V, W)$ would be a subset of all mappings $V\to W$, however, I am confused about how a linear mapping can be a vector subspace at all.

Furthermore, the exercise then asks:
Show that:
$$dim(Hom_F(V, W))= (dim V )(dim W)$$

How can a homomorphism have a dimension in the same way as a vector space? I cannot conceptualize this. I know a linear mapping $Hom(,)$  is isomorphic to $Mat(,)$, the set of matrices ×, where $=dim$ and $=dim$, thus the dimension can be found this way.
But my solution set refers to letting $f_{ij} : V \to W$ and claiming that $f_{ij}$ is linear, and also that ${\{f_{ij}\}}_{i\in I,j\in J}$ is linearly independent. I cannot see how this is related to the above question at all.

Looking for someone to clear up everything going on here. Thanks!

Comment: $\operatorname{Hom}_{F}(V, W)$ is the *set* of all linear maps (vector space homomorphisms)  from $V$ to $W$ - you appear to think it is a single linear map, but then correctly note that it is isomorphic, as a vector space, to the *set* of all matrices..

Comment: So does $Hom_F(,)$ refer to the set of all images of $V$ under $f$? Or is it the set $\{f_1,...f_n\}$ where $f_i$ are all linear maps. The latter confuses me as, I can see how these functions can be linearly independent etc. but fail to see how this is a vector subspace or can be a generating set if $f$ are not explicitly vectors.

Comment: It's the latter. Please check the abstract notion of a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).